# How to add property "Alternate" to an image file on server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, upload, asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net core and web api for uploading images.

On server:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Upload")]
public class UploadApiController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public UploadApiController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

On client:

```
// Files is an array that contains all temporary images for uploading.
let Files = [];

let image_preview = function (file) {
    file['Alternate'] = 'alternate_text';
    Files.push(file);

    // other implements...
};

$('button#upload').click(function () {
    let formData = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < Files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('files', Files[i])
    }

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/api/upload', true);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log('uploading...')
    };  

    xhr.send(formData);  
});
```

Snapshot:

[image: 1]

My question: how to add new property "Alternate" to `ICollection<IFormFile> files` to detect property `Alternate` that is sent from client (formData)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the answer for question `How to add property “Alternate” to an image file on server?` but it seems like solving the problem (sending image file with alternate text).

On server:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[HttpPost]
public async Task Post(ICollection<IFormFile> files, IList<string> alts)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> _alts = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var alt in alts)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(alt);

        foreach (var item in temp)
        {
            _alts.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

    }
}
```

On client:

```
for (let i = 0; i < Files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('files', Files[i]);

    let name = Files[i]['name'],
        alt = {};

    alt[name] = 'alt_text';

    formData.append('alts', JSON.stringify(alt));
}
```

We would never get duplicate key in the dictionary because `Files[i]['name']` is always primary and cannot be changed (hacking by someone) if we've checked duplicate uploading file before.

Then, we can merge the file name (in `files`) with `Key` in `_alts` to get Alternate text.

Snapshot:

[image: 2]

**UPDATE:** The code in the snapshot was wrong.